# Show any changes made by one client to be seen by other clients in WCF C# using Single instance

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

This a snippet of a code from a project I am working on, it goes multiple clients connect to WCF service(host), the host is to detect any changes made to the service Library database and to display to each client the changes that have been made by which, it show  the value changed, the IP address of the client that made that change.

```
    private void RaisedPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    public string GetIP()
    {
        OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
        MessageProperties prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
        RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint =
           prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
        string ip = endpoint.Address;
        Console.WriteLine("Client Ip" + ip);

        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: It does doesn't Display the client Info to other clients connected(the values that have been changed)rather , it continues to work on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- One way is using a *Duplex Contract*

[How to: Create a Duplex Contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-create-a-duplex-contract)

> The duplex contract is one of three message patterns available to
>   Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services. The other two message
>   patterns are one-way and request-reply. A duplex contract consists of
>   two one-way contracts between the client and the server and does not
>   require that the method calls be correlated. Use this kind of contract
>   when your service must query the client for more information or
>   explicitly raise events on the client

- You could also use *Signalr*

[Introduction to SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

> ASP.NET SignalR is a library for ASP.NET developers that simplifies
>   the process of adding real-time web functionality to applications.
>   Real-time web functionality is the ability to have server code push
>   content to connected clients instantly as it becomes available, rather
>   than having the server wait for a client to request new data.

- Lastly you could just poll the Wcf service for last change information

*WFC* and *Duplex Contracts* is very secure an reliable way to achieve your results. *Signalr* is a very lightweight approach and is'nt as robust or secure.

In this situation, if you don't need security and just a light weight approach, id be inclined go with *Signalr*

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have figured out how to do it

Comment: @EdwinKaburu if this helped make sure you upvote and mark as correct answer. Or if you found a different approach, consider writing your own answer and marking it correct. it helps other people with similar problems